# Eliminating gaps and overlaps in layer of SpatiaLite table

Tags: qgis, spatialite

I'm try to snap all polygons in a table to remove gaps and overlaps.

I can remove gaps but get new overlaps.

I have no idea what doing wrong.  I am new  in SpatiaLite.

I tried the following:

1 - generated the set of neighboring polygons

```
CREATE VIEW toques as
       SELECT "s"."cd_geocodi" as "geocodi",
              ST_UNARYUNION(ST_COLLECT(i.geom_sb)) as geom_sb
         FROM "T_SetBog" AS "s", "T_SetBog" as "i"
        WHERE "s"."cd_geocodi" != "i"."cd_geocodi" AND
              (ST_TOUCHES(s.geom_sb, i.geom_sb) = 1 or
              ST_OVERLAPS(s.geom_sb, i.geom_sb) = 1)
     GROUP BY "s"."cd_geocodi"
```

2 - fix the polygons to match the edges of neighboring (epsg: 4674)

```
CREATE VIEW setsnap as
       SELECT "s"."cd_geocodi" as "geocodi",
              ST_SNAP(s.geom_sb, i.geom_sb, 0.000001) as geom_sb
         FROM "T_SetBog" AS "s", "toques" as "i"
        WHERE "s"."cd_geocodi" = "i"."geocodi"
```

3 - fixes in the table

```
UPDATE "T_SetBog" SET geom_sb = 
                 (SELECT geom_sb FROM "setsnap"
                   WHERE cd_geocodi = geocodi)
```